# Change distance between nodes in tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am attempting to do this, but I cannot seem to find the correct syntax for it in LaTeX.

Here is what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
                \begin{graph}[layered layout,nodes={draw,circle, node distance=10cm}]
                    {1->[edge label=bob, node distance=3cm]2};
                \end{graph}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

None of the `node distance` commands seem to have an impact

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `layered layout` ignores node distance; however, you can use `level sep` (and possibly `sibling sep` if necessary):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,graphs}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
                \begin{graph}[layered layout,nodes={draw,circle},level sep=2cm]
                    {1->[edge label=bob]2};
                \end{graph}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So a combination of level sep and sibling sep will force it to be that distance at least between nodes?

Comment: As an aside, how can I represent a self loop on one of these nodes?

Comment: @soandos those values will set the distance between the center of the nodes from one level to the nodes on the next level (`level sep`) and between siblings (`sibling sep`); but, in fact, it is weird that `node distance` is having no effect.

Comment: @soandos for the loop, question, an example: `\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
                \begin{graph}[layered layout,nodes={draw,circle}]
                    {1->[edge label=bob]2->[loop right]2};
                \end{graph}
            \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: So the fact that node distance is not having an affect is a bug?

Comment: @soandos No. I found the reason: the `layered layout` ignores this key. Others honour it (`simple necklace layout`, for example).